# Spark query 100 billion rows of data out from elasticsearch very slow

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-5

I recently use spark 2.2 to query a huge elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes and 1000 billion rows of data. And I used org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.5.0 for spark-es integration.

However, the result set is too large (contains 100 billions rows of data) and spark job will use 2 hours to finish it.

I confirmed that all fields are simple String types and my program is right(without setting some optimize options) and spark did pushDown to help minimize the output, but still it's too large. Following are my configurations when using spark, any optimize suggestions?

```
es.scroll.size="10000"
pushdown="true" 
es.scroll.keepalive="10m"
```

My spark sql code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Simple Example")
    .set("es.resource", "myIndex/info")
    .set("es.read.field","field1, field2, field3")
    .set("es.scroll.size","10000")
    .set("es.scroll.keepalive","10m")
    .set("es.nodes","192.168.12.12")
    .set("es.port","9200")
    .set("pushdown","true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
val df = sc.sql("select * from myIndex where name = 'exampleName'")
```

And I check on spark UI, the event timeline implied that `Executor compute time` is too long .

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, spark can NOT use elasticsearch's index to accelerate querying, so it would read all the documents in the index while executing a simple term query. How fast do you expect to read 1000 billion rows via HTTP?

Comment: @aLeX r u kidding me? Of course spark can do pushdown, by using this package https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20 and won't read all data in the index

Comment: May you show the Spark code that you use to query Elasticsearch?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev ok, I added, just normal spark sql codes

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now. I could only found [this ES forum issue](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/spark-sql-filter-pushdown/46985) that might be relevant.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev I am sure spark sql did push down, I think it has nothing to do with the program, it's about resources and configurations.

Comment: It looks like it still downloads the entire result set, either the result set is very big or there is a bug/problem of misconfiguration. If you are sure that the result set is small, then it's the latter, sorry I don't have expertise in this particular question. If you set a `LIMIT 10` does it do the pushdown?